# Network Subnet Mask

Tags: network

what is the slash form of the subnet mask 255.224.252.0 and if it is invalid, then why is it invalid. I am having trouble with this address mask. Could anyone help!

Comment: IP addresses and masks are binary numbers. Convert the dotted-decimal, which is only for human readability, into binary, then it becomes obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Subnet masks are always in the form (left to right) of contiguous ones, followed by zeros.  You can't have ones, then zeros, then more ones.  If you convert your mask to binary, you will see that you don't have a valid mask for exactly that reason.